# PUT API with path parameter and request body

Tags: json, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have a PUT API Gateway endpoint which should be used to update a DynamoDB entry.

The id for that DynamoDB entry is given as the path parameter.

I have the following mapping template:

```
"application/json": {
    "id": "$input.params('id')",
    "title": "$input.json('$.title')"
}
```

The id is returned as expected.

If I submit this request body

```
{
  "title": "Hello world" 
}
```

I get the error `Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character (\'t\'`

Here's the overview of my AWS management console:

[image]

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

So I just found the solution:

`"title": "$input.json('$.title')"`

should be

`"title": $input.json('$.title')` (without the double quotes).

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-variable-reference